# How to append dataframes together in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that is the output of machine learning predictions like this:

```
predictions = model.transform(test_data)
+-----------------+-----------------+-----+------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|col1_imputed     |col2_imputed     |label|          features|row_num|       rawPrediction|         probability|prediction|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----+------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|        -0.002353|           0.9762|    0|[-0.002353,0.9762]|      1|[-0.8726465863653...|[0.29470390100153...|       1.0|
|         -0.08637|          0.06524|    0|[-0.08637,0.06524]|      3|[-0.6029409441836...|[0.35367114067727...|



root
 |-- col1_imputed: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2_imputed: double (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- row_num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = false)
```

I convert the `probability` column to select only the positive predictions in its vector, but I want to append this new conversion to the dataframe above (or replace the currently probability column with this new one of only positive probabilities) and I'm getting errors when trying this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

secondelement=udf(lambda v:float(v[1]),FloatType())
pos_prob = predictions.select(secondelement('probability')) #selects second element in probability column

#trying to add the new pos_prob column and naming it 'prob' to the dataframe:
df = predictions.withColumn('prob', predictions.select(secelement('probability'))).collect()

AssertionError: col should be Column
```

I have also tried wrapping `lit()` around it from reading similar questions but this gives another error:

```
df = all_preds.withColumn('prob', lit(all_preds.select(secelement('probability')))).collect()

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UDF with `withColumn`, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

secondelement = udf(lambda v: float(v[1]), FloatType())
df = predictions.withColumn('prob', secondelement('probability'))
```